# Description Resource Path Location Type Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact

Tags: macos, maven, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

I am getting the following error when ever i created a maven project in kepler Mac OS X.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:maven-plugin:2.10:runtime Cause: error in opening zip file pom.xml

I tried on JUNO also same error i am facing.

I tried to install m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin also from

https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e-extras/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201206251206/

I am trying to fix this from past one week but not able too it..

Thanks,